# "That's no (inanimate object), that's my WIFE!" (mid 1970's audio media)

Tags: story-identification, audio-book, radio-play

I've searched several different ways and I find what look like they could be references to the line I am thinking of, but I can't find an authoritative reference.

I am remembering an audio media story circa mid 1970's that could have been a [radio play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_drama) or possibly an [album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Album) or [single](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_(music)) and possibly performed by [The Firesign Theatre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Firesign_Theatre) or some similar group.

These types of works were listened to in situations where memory was detrimentally impacted.

The only thing I remember now is (most of) the last line:

> That's no (inanimate object), that's my WIFE!

The inanimate object was a chair or a toaster or a radio or something mundane. For some reason I think it might have been three syllables long.

---

Addressing topicality as science fiction, I am 90%+ sure that at some point during the story the main character's wife was *transformed* into the inanimate object *via some technology*. The exclamation of surprise upon recognizing that the inanimate object was originally the main character's wife is a good clue that she was not an inanimate object when they were first married.

Comment: If it is indeed "No Anchovies Please" by the J. Geils Band then the story is sort of sci fi + comedy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might be the 'song' (it's actually spoken-word) called *No Anchovies, Please* by J. Geils Band.  It can be found on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63yyMxlBhZs).  It's on their *Love Stinks* album from 1980, but maybe it was on the radio earlier?

> Meanwhile, back in Portland, Maine... her husband Don, now chain-smoking 40 packs of cigarettes a day, sits at a Local bar and has a few beers with the regulars. Bored, everyone's attention turns to the television set that just hangs from the wall. ("Welcome to Bowling for Dollars"). Suddenly, crazy Al says, "S-say, Don, There sure is something familiar about that bowling ball. " To which a terrified Don replies, "Oh my God! That bowling ball! It's my wife!"

It can qualify as science fiction, because it involves :

> three scientists who are engaged in diabolical, avant-garde experiments previously performed only on insects and other small, meaningless creatures

Comment: you beat me by 11 seconds! I was going to say the same thing

Comment: Ah, yes, this of course is exactly it, anchovies and all; *thanks!* 1980 fits too, it was all such a blur back then...